# How can I check whether a button (wpv_1266351) in a frame does or does not exist using Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: jquery

iframe Info:  id="AssessmentsIFrame"

button Info: id="wpv_1266351"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#wpv_1266351');
```

Comment: but how can I test it for null?

Comment: var t = $('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#wpv_1266351').length || null;

Comment: I tried it like this:if($('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#titlediv_1266231').length == null)              
                {                  alert('a');          
                    setTimeout('DisplayUploadButtons()', 1000); 
                    return;
                } and got no alert with no button.

Comment: That won't work. Try: if ($('#AssessmentsIFrame').contents().find('#wpv_1266351').length) { // the id exists } else { // the id does not exist }

Answer (score 0):

First, the iframe HAS to be on the same domain name, otherwise you can't get to anything in it.

```
var ifr = $('#'),
 ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || (ifr.contentWindow && ifr.contentWindow.document) || ifr.document,
 button = ifrDoc.getElementById('wpv_1266351');
```

button will either be null or a reference to your button.  It's not really any simpler using jQUery since jQuery doesn't know how to get the iframe document reference by itself.